# What is "classpath mode", as seen in WildFly documentation?

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-16

The [WildFly documentation for version 16](https://www.wildfly.org/news/2019/02/27/WildFly16-Final-Released/) says

> WildFly 16 also is heavily tested and runs well on Java 8. We plan to
> continue to support Java 8 at least through WildFly 18.
>
> Please note that WildFly **runs on Java 11 and 12 in classpath mode**.

What does this mean?

Comment: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/doc/jdk-modularization-tips

Comment: @Michael: So it supports? -> https://www.wildfly.org/news/2019/02/27/WildFly16-Final-Released/

Comment: Yes, it clearly says "WildFly runs on Java 11".

Answer (score 1):

'Classpath mode' is just how Java has always previously worked prior to the introduction of the Java 9 module system.

It is used in juxtaposition to 'module mode'.

> **Classpath mode**
>
> At compile-time, a Java compiler does not directly
> compile a module declaration.
>
> Observability (JLS 7.3) is determined solely by the host system, and
> consistently for all compilation units. The host system typically
> considers classes on the classpath and/or sourcepath as the entire
> observable universe (plus classes named on the command line).
>
> This is how Java works today.

See [Project Jigsaw: JDK Modularization Tips](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/doc/jdk-modularization-tips)

Comment: So Wildlfy 16 runs on Java 11? And i can move on same?